# How to hide PHP file extension without using .htaccess

Tags: php

How am I able to hide a `.php` extension in an URL address, so that this address:

```
http://www.thesite.com/somefile.php
```

would look like:

```
http://www.thesite.com/somefile
```

*without* the use of the `.htaccess` file. The reason for that being because I have many directories and would want to hide the extension on all those files in every directory. I have tried to set `expose_php` to off, and this still fails with error 404.

I am using PHP 5.3.10 and Apache server.

Comment: That's not what `expose_php` does.

Comment: mod-rewire is the correct approach

Comment: Why do you think that using .htaccess can't achieve this?

Comment: This is one of the oldest, but others are: *[Hide PHP file extension from the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46539366)* (incomplete title, 2017), *[Remove file extensions without using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41806732)* (2017), *[Hide .php without htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40032552)* (2016, but without answers), and *[Is it possible to hide a .php extension or replace .php with .html in a URL without htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25293879)* (2014)."

Answer (score 5):

Although you specifically said no, using the `.htaccess` file would remove the `.php` extension from all PHP files in all subdirectories in a site. I think that is what you are going for.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
</IfModule>
```

Putting that into the `.htaccess` file will remove all the .php file extensions. *Or* you could put it directly into the webserver's configuration files.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with [URL rewriting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine). If you don't want to use .htaccess, you can write the rule in your host configuration file.

Comment: How exactly and where? Where is the host configuration file and what is its name? E.g., can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

URL rewriting is quite a heavy-handed approach when the much simpler [MultiViews](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html#multiviews) exists

In a `<Directory>`, `<Location>` or `<Files>` section of your httpd configuration (or in `.htaccess` if allowed by `AllowOverride`)...

```apache
Options MultiViews
```

From the documentation...

> The effect of `MultiViews` is as follows: if the server receives a request for `/some/dir/foo`, if `/some/dir` has `MultiViews` enabled, and `/some/dir/foo` does not exist, then the server reads the directory looking for files named `foo.*`, and effectively fakes up a type map which names all those files, assigning them the same media types and content-encodings it would have if the client had asked for one of them by name

Note that conflicting files and directories may cause problems so try not to have both `foo.php` and `foo.html` or `foo/` in the same directory.