# Is it possible to hide a .php extension or replace .php with .html in a URL without htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have tried to find the answer, but I failed. Other questions are **with [htaccess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.htaccess)**.

I found [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9865573/how-to-hide-php-file-extension-without-using-htaccess) similar of my question, but I did not get my answer.

I need it ***without .htaccess***, because I do not have permission of **[URL rewriting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine)** in my client's server.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: no, you can't. htaccess is just a way to override httpd.conf settings. if you don't have .htaccess rights, then you definitely don't have httpd.conf rights, and nothing you can do in your PHP code will suddenly make the server "ignore" `.php` or tell the server to treat `.html` as if it was `.php`.

Comment: @anubhava How can I do it using `header` function ?

Comment: Actually I misspoke. I agree with @MarcB here. If `.php` extension is missing then your `php` scripts won't be even called.

Comment: Have you tried using a .html or .htm file with `<?php` and `?>`? Normally the apache module add the parsing of *.html and/or *.htm files to the list, if i recall it right...

Comment: Does this answer your question? *[How to hide PHP file extension without using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9865573/how-to-hide-php-file-extension-without-using-htaccess)*

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have access to your `.htaccess` or `httpd.conf` file the you could  set up a proxy (like nginx) in front of the web server, point the DNS record to this proxy and have the proxy rewrite the requests from .html to .php to pass on to your apache server.

However, if you don't have access to .htaccess or httpd.conf files, you probably don't control the DNS records...