# Hide PHP file extension from the URL

Tags: php, html, url-rewriting

I am storing my website's content in a database. It is like a CMS. One will add page content from an admin panel, and content will stored in the database.

In one page, I have added 10-12 links as `<a href="page.php/abc"` and my URLs looks like `www.example.com/page.php/abc`. I want to hide `.php` from `page.php`. How can I do this without using .htaccess?

I have tried with `str_replace` (added in page content from the CMS), but it seems like it does not recognise it as PHP code and take it as a string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide PHP file extension without using .htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9865573/how-to-hide-php-file-extension-without-using-htaccess)

Comment: It suggest .htaccess method and I need it to do by any other method not .htaccess

Comment: The title of the proposed duplicate includes *"**without** using .htaccess"*, and one of the answers does not suggest it.

Comment: There is a dilemma here. Updating the question to include the later discovered requirement of not using .htaccess (e.g. include it in the title) will invalidate one answer.

Comment: Other candidates: *[Remove file extensions without using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41806732)* (2017), *[Hide .php without htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40032552)* (2016, but without answers), and *[Is it possible to hide a .php extension or replace .php with .html in a URL without htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25293879)* (2014).

Answer (score 5):

You can do this in the following way:

Either put this code in your [htaccess file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.htaccess) (which you don't want), or put this code in your server's configuration file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
</IfModule>
```

This will hide .php from all URLs of your website.

That's it.

Comment: What is the name of the server's configuration file? And where is it located? (Please respond by [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46539466/edit), not here in comments (as appropriate).)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [URI rewriting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine), depending on your webserver. For Apache, you can specify it in a [.htaccess file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.htaccess), but for [nginx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx), you need to edit the server block of the domain to allow that.

Basically, you need to tell it to rewrite any request like `www.example.com/page/abc` to `www.example.com/page.php/abc` (internally, not displayed in the URI bar).

Comment: is it not possible without htaccess, for apache?

Comment: see @amrinder-singh answer if you don't want to use .htaccess. You will need to edit the apache config file to do so.

Answer (score -1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: This does not work if you have a folder with the same name

Comment: It worked nicely, thanks to  Mr Mehmet