# Hide .php without htaccess

Tags: php, url

I have been able to load my pages into the index page from a folder. But my major problem now is to hide the .php extension in my index.

For example, my page's URL when loaded into the index is `index.php?pg=Dashboard`.

Here is my code

```
<?php
    $dir = 'port/';
    if (!empty($_GET['pg'])) {
        $pages = scandir($dir, 0);
        unset($pages[0], $pages[1]);
        $pageinc = $_GET['pg'];
        if (in_array($pageinc . '.load.php', $pages)) {
            include($dir . '/' . $pageinc . '.load.php');
        }
        else {
            include($dir . '/ErrorPage.php');
        }
    }
    else {
        include($dir . '/Dashboard.load.php');
    }
?>
```

Is there a way of using this method and still hide the .php extension over the URL?

I want it to appear like *"index?pg=Dashboard"*.

Comment: Just redirect without the `.php` extension.

Comment: you mean i should do this <a href="index?pg=Dashboard" >next page</a>     instead of <a href="index.php?pg=Dashboard" >next page</a>

Comment: yes, this. I'm not sure if it will work. Maybe you'd like to look into routes.

Comment: it didnt work actually, couldnt point to the page. 404

Comment: Why without `htaccess`?

Comment: Obviously that cannot work just like that. Http servers cannot somehow magically _guess_ what you want to happen. You indeed can output links like that, you actually have to if you want the links to look like that. But you also have to take care that they can be interpreted on the receiving side, so on the level of the http server that reacts to the request. That means you need to implement internal rewriting rules. You do not have to do that in `.htaccess` style files. You can and actually should prefer to do so in the host configuration. Take a look at the documentation, I'd say!

Comment: @chris85 it never works for me

Comment: @arkascha which documentation? may i get hold it...Can what i want be achievable using php

Comment: No, this cannot be done on php level, since the request will never reach php without internal rewriting. Not until you completely reconfigure the behavior of the whole http server which certainly is a very bad idea. Take a look at the documentation of apache's rewriting module. It is, as all those open source documentations, of excellent quality and comes with great and realistic examples: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: If your only issue is that you fail to succeed in using `.htaccess` style files then I suggest you solve that issue instead of turning away and trying exotic approaches.

Comment: Why do you need to do this in the first place?

Comment: Does this answer your question? *[How to hide PHP file extension without using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9865573/how-to-hide-php-file-extension-without-using-htaccess)*