# Remove file extensions without using .htaccess

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting

Is there a way of removing file extensions from my URLs without using .htaccess?

Like if my URL is http://example.com/index.html, can I make it http://example.com/index without using .htaccess?

The reason I ask is because I do not have access to the .htaccess file.

Comment: How come you don't have access to the .htaccess file? It's just a regular file in the document root. If you're using FTP, just make sure that you have turned on "view hidden files" in your client.

Comment: A few minutes ago I did not know what a .htaccess file is but now I do:) Problem is I am unable to upload it

Comment: That sounds like an permissions issue. Talk to the owner/administrator of the server to get that sorted.

Comment: Okay. Thanks alot!:-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? *[How to hide PHP file extension without using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9865573/how-to-hide-php-file-extension-without-using-htaccess)*

Answer (score 1):

You can have urls like `http://example.com/index.php/your/fancy/url`
out of the box with PHP5. You can then read the URL parameters using

```
echo $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];
```

Remember to validate/filter the PATH_INFO and all other request variables before using them in your application.

Comment: That link only says how you can produce a link like that, not how you could _use_ or _implement_ it without htaccess.